# How to repeat "for" loop based on response?

Tags: python, for-loop, break

Currently, I have a program that reads data from a text file, parses it with a function,and  will output it to another file. My issue is that my function uses get requests, and gets rate-limited frequently, returning a 429. I'm trying to make the program detect the 429 response, wait 300 seconds, then repeat from the line that previously failed. I've tried a nested while loop inside the for loops but I can't seem to get it working. My code is shown below:

```
for line in lines: # lines is from input file readlines()
    data = item_data(line)  #item_data returns (data, response code)
    if data[1] != 429:
        with open('out.csv', 'a') as f:
            f.write("Parsed data here!")
        print('Success!')
    else:
        time.sleep(300)
        print(Failed)
        #repeat item_data from line
f.close()
```

An example output of what I want it to do would be:

```
1 
Success!
2
Success!
3
Success!
4
Failed
4
Success!
5
Success!
```

Comment: You need to add a nested loop that repeats the `item_data(line)` as long as there's a 429 response.

Comment: @martineau is there a way to do that while only calling item_data once? If not, how would do it with the minimum number of item_data calls?

Comment: No, a 429 response (Too Many Requests) specifically requires at least one additional attempt to be made in order to be successful. I don't know what `item_data()` is, but it could be made to automatically retry on 429s (then you would not have to deal with them at this level of coding).

Answer (score 1):

You want to retry the same line again.

```
for line in lines: # lines is from input file readlines()
    while True:
        data = item_data(line)  #item_data returns (data, response code)
        if data[1] != 429:
            break
        # else:
        print(Failed)
        #do something
        time.sleep(300)
    with open('out.csv', 'a') as f:
        f.write("Parsed data here!")
    print('Success!')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (no need to close a file if you're using a `with` statement):

```py
with open('some_file.txt') as x: # Replace 'some_file.txt' with your file
    lines = x.readlines()
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        print(i + 1) # Will print 1, 2, 3, etc.
        data, code = item_data(line)
        if code != 429:
            with open('out.csv', 'a') as f:
                f.write(str(data)) # Or whatever you want to write
            print('Success!')
        else:
            print(f'Failed with code {code}. Waiting 300s')
            time.sleep(300)
```

Comment: Maybe also print _before_ sleeping in the failure case.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 0):

Your for command clause must be:

```py
data = item_data(line)
while data[1]==429:
    print('fail')
    time.sleep(300)
    data = item_data(line)
with open('out.csv', 'a') as f:
    f.write("Parsed data here!")
print('Success!')
```

It is the easiest way that you can apply just change your condition

Comment: I don't think this repeats the loop from the current line

Comment: You must add yor for loop before this command. I note this for you in the first row